# TeamCity: How to get the last build metadata for each build type using the REST API

Tags: teamcity

Right now to get a list of the last build for each build type I have to:

- Get all the build types through this endpoint: `/guestAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/`
- Get the last build metadata for **each** `buildType`: `/guestAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:BUILD_TYPE_ID/builds/?locator=lookupLimit:1`

This is very inefficient as I have to make as many requests as there are `buildTypes`.

The REST API does not allow to specify more than one `BUILD_TYPE_ID` per request to the endpoint.

Is there a way to aggregate this requests? Is it possible to get the last build metadata for each `buildType` in one go?

I am using TeamCity 8.1.

Comment: I'm not sure about getting ALL your builds in one script but you can certainly get the last successful build for each build ..
`wget.exe http://teamcity.domain.com/httpAuth/repository/downloadAll/btx/.lastFinished/ --user=<user> --password=<password> --output-document=artifacts.7z`

Comment: @wal To clarify, I don't want to get the artifact, I want to get the build metadata from the REST API.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
http://teamcity.jetbrains.com/app/rest/buildTypes?locator=affectedProject:(id:TeamCityPluginsByJetBrains)&fields=buildType(id,name,builds($locator(running:false,canceled:false,count:1),build(number,status,statusText)))
```

Check comments on [this JetBrains' ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-22717#comment=27-681190) for further details.